# Jacobian linearization: There is not an equilibrium point set

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, jacobian, linearization

[image]To apply Jacobian linearization procedure, we should find equilibrium points of the system. But, in some nonlinear systems, it is impossible to find equilibrium points set which make system's differential equations equal to zero. So, we have to handle the problem in another way.

I have this kind of nonlinear system and cannot find equilibrium points. What do you suggest me to linearize this nonlinear system with Jacobian matrices?

I tried to solve this problem with optimization methods in MATLAB via fmincon, but I think it is not a clear way.

My reference source is: http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/system/nonlinear/linearization/linearization.html

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For linearization, it is not necessarily that the linearization point is an equilibrium. For $x$ being the state and $u$ being the input signal, you have $$\dot{x} = f(x,u) = f(x_0,u_0)+A(x-x_0)+B(u-u_0)+H.O.T.$$ Here $A$ and $B$ are the linearization (Jacobian) matrices, $$A = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,u)|_{x=x_0,\, u=u_0}$$ and $$B = \frac{\partial}{\partial u}f(x,u)|_{x=x_0,\, u=u_0}.$$

If $x_0$, $u_0$ are an equilibrium, then you have $f(x_0,u_0) = 0$; otherwise, the constant term will remain.

For $x_0=0$ and $u_0=0$ we have the standard linearization: $\dot{x} \approx Ax + Bu$. However, if $x_0$, $u_0$ is not the origin, then you should work with the deviations $\tilde{x}=x-x_0$ and $\tilde{u}=u-u_0$.

Finally, you obtain $$\dot{\tilde x} = A \tilde x + B \tilde u + C,$$ where $C = f(x_0,u_0)$ is the constant term that you must take into account for control design.

Comment: Hi Arastas! In my simulation u1 and u2 are 0.1 and 100 respectively. According to them, i calculate x1, x2, x3 of equilibrium by making 3 differential equations equal to 0. After that obtain state space model by Jacobians. My model doesn't contain constant terms which you say. When i obtain state space, apply two inputs (u1=0.1 step, u2=100 step) and get the outputs. Is there any missing in my work?

Comment: I think, this question may be answer of my problem: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/395743/automatic-control-linearization-with-two-states

Comment: Ok, so you have $u_{1,0}=0.1$ and $u_{2,0}=100$ (let say they are coupled as $u_0$) and they yield some $x_0$ such that $f(x_0,u_0)=0$, i.e., you have found an equilibrium. Great. Now you consider the deviations $\tilde{x}$ and $\tilde{u}$. Your linearization is a linear model in deviations, not in the original signal. I.e., you measure $x$ as the output signal, you compute the deviation $\tilde{x}(t)=x(t)-x_0$, you compute your control law, e.g., $\tilde{u}(t)=-K\tilde{x}(t)$, and you compute the input control signal as $u(t) = \tilde{u}+u_0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arastas. But I'm still not sure how i can obtain the output of my linearized system according to my step inputs. To get response, can i directly apply inputs to my linearized model which is created by Jacobians by using equilibriums i calculated? I'm new in working with state space models and have confusion. Sorry because of a lot of questions. :)

Comment: Input to your linearized system is not $u$ but $\tilde{u}=u-u_0$.

Comment: Thanks Arastas!